# Rails use RABL and jbuilder in the same app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl, jbuilder

I have a Rails app that is currently using RABL for json.  I have code I can copy that's written in jbuilder.  Eventually, I want to confer the app to all jbuilder.

But, in the mean time, can I have both RABL and jbuilder in the same app?

For instance have both of these type files:

```
locations.json.jbuilder
show.json.rabl
```

Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I've done it, no problem. RABL and JBUILDER can coexist in the same rails project.

As long as you don't use a RABL and JBUILDER view with the same name.  My recollection is that the jbuilder view took precedence but that might have been a quirk of my application.

Personally I prefer the flexibility of RABL... it gives you both json and xml for no extra cost.

Comment: How do you specify the order of template lookup? i.e., if I installed RABL first then jbuilder, it always looks for .rabl file first then if not found, it looks for .jbuilder. Because I have the two template file coexisting due to legacy app needs, so I need to find a way to avoid having to specify jbuilder each time.